# syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer-20.1.60-beta Error: Method 'addObserver' cannot be called on 'WidgetsBinding?' because it is null

Tags: android, flutter, dart, syncfusion, pdf-viewer

Error occurring while using syncfution_flutter_pdfviewer-20.1.60-beta version
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrgJf.png)

Answer (score 1):

As error said you should change

```
WidgetsBinding?.instance.addPostFrameCallback
```

To

```
WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly upgrade to the latest version of Flutter SDK to get the issue resolved.
Flutter SDK setup link for the latest version: https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows#get-the-flutter-sdk